# Opening an MVC3 project on a machine without MVC3 installed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, gac

I've read the blog posts on deploying MVC3 projects to shared hosting environments that do not have MVC3 installed:

http://www.iwantmymvc.com/2011-03-23-bin-deploy-aspnet-mvc-3-visual-studio

I'm opening an MVC3 project in VS2010 on a machine that does not have MVC3 installed. I have added the references to my *.csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Razor">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure">
<HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I'm still getting the following error:

> The project type is not supported by this installation.

I'll open up the project on a machine with MVC3 installed and browse to the references, which correctly points to the local lib file. What am I missing?

Comment: Going by the error message ...  it seems you are missing the VS.NET project template for MVC.  Maybe copying it from a machine that has it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/01/20/opening-an-asp-net-mvc-project-without-having-asp-net-mvc-installed-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation.aspx